# Possible to change the placeholder in dynamic crm 2016?

Tags: dynamics-crm

"--" is the placeholder used in the latest microsoft dynamic CRM versions to indicate an empty field, Is is possible to change the placeholder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a supported way to do it. You would have to figure out how to modify the form elements to display something else, and then add a script to each form onload to replace all of the placeholders initially and and also change handlers to every field to replace the placeholder whenever a user empties a field.  It would be liable to break with any product update.

Comment: thats fine, but i want default place holder ## instead of --. Is there any option ?